# Blazor Server 7.0 app with graph Azure AD authentication and OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut

Tags: azure, authentication, blazor-server-side

I'm new to Blazor, but a long-time asp.net developer.  I'm trying to do a new application in Blazor that requires Azure AD authentication.  I've managed to piece together almost everything and get the solution working.  I've registered the application in Microsoft Entry ID, configured the appsettings.json file, and added the "example" code I've managed to scrounge up into the Program.cs file.

Everything works, pretty much, as advertised except for the "Redirect" on logout.  I can get that working, but the change causes the "login" and "Logout" actions to change, which is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Here is the behavior I want (except for the last step that displays the blank page)

Without the redirect change, the application opens and presents a default page with a login link, which when clicked does the following:

1. The Microsoft "Pick an Account" pop-up window appears
2. The user clicks the account (or "Use another account") option
3. The user is logged in, and the default home page is displayed with an option to logout.
4. The user clicks the "Logout" link.
5. Microsoft "Pick an Account" pop-up window appears
6. The user clicks the appropriate account
7. Pop-up changes to "Wait while we log you out"
8. Pop-up changes to "Successfully logged out and you should close all browsers"
9. Pop-up goes away and the user is redirected to a blank screen.

When I add the following code:

```cs
            builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
                {
                    context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/";
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
                    context.HandleResponse();

                };
            });
```

and then run the application, I get a very different login process:

1. User Clicks login button
2. The user's current domain account (similar to asp.net when IIS is set for Windows authentication) is logged in.
3. User Clicks logout button
4. The user is logged out and redirected to the application default page.

I like the simplicity of the logout process, however, I need the original login process (prompting for which account to log in) to continue to work.

Am I missing something in the Event handler setup?  If I take that section of code out, the application returns to the previous login/logout process.

In case it helps, here is the entire "public class Program":

```cs
    public class Program
    {
        //Local private variable to provide read access to the Application Configuration file "appsettings.json"
        private static readonly IConfiguration appConfig_ = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            //BEGIN: JLK - 231107
            // Added the following items to handle configuration to use Microsoft identity for Authentication and Authorization
            var initialScopes = appConfig_.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

            // This is required to be instantiated before the OpenIdConnectOptions starts getting configured.
            // By default, the claims mapping will map claim names in the old format to accommodate older SAML applications.
            // 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role' instead of 'roles'
            // This flag ensures that the ClaimsIdentity claims collection will be built from the claims in the token.
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

            // Add authentication with Microsoft identity platform.
            // EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi - adds support for the web app to acquire tokens to call the API.
            // AddMicrosoftGraph - adds support to call Microsoft Graph
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(appConfig_.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(appConfig_.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
                //options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy; --This was the original "policy" (I don't fully understand this yet) but it caused the "login" to occur before app displayed

                //This policy seems to allow the application to display without authentication, allowing the user to press the "login" button.
                var policy_ = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                      .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                      .Build();
                options.AddPolicy("Required", policy_);
            });

            // Add the incremental consent and conditional access handler for Blazor server side pages.
            builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

            //Added the following section to handle redirection user to app home page after successful logout
            //NOTE: After adding this code I notice that I no loger get the login prompt to select an account, nor do I get the logout prompt to select which account to logout
            //      but it does seem to work and user is redirected to the home page..
            builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
                {
                    context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/";
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
                    context.HandleResponse();

                };
            });
            //END: JLK - 231107

            //-------------Original STuff-------------------------
            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
            //builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            //BEGIN: JLK - 231107
            //added to to handle authorization and authentication
            // NOTE: I have not found any difference in app with both UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization() commented out, so not really sure what these do.
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.MapControllers();
            //END: JLK - 231107

            app.MapBlazorHub();
            app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
```

I tried adding the Redirect event code and expected the original login/logout process with only the final page after logout to be the application home page rather than the blank page it seems to default to.  I've seen other examples where the "last page" (blank for me) is a simple page (not inside the application layout form) that says "xxxx user has been successfully logged out".

Comment: I can successfully Log in and Log out when I comment on these lines of [code](https://i.imgur.com/rsOru0q.png).

Answer (score 0):

*I was able to run the app successfully by making the below changes.
I have removed the below lines from your code,*

> ```cs
> //context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/";
> //context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
> //context.HandleResponse();
> ```

**Code :**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

public class Program
{
    private static readonly IConfiguration appConfig_ = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        var initialScopes = appConfig_.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(appConfig_.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                    .AddMicrosoftGraph(appConfig_.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            var policy_ = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                  .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                  .Build();
            options.AddPolicy("Required", policy_);
        });

        builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
        builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
            {
                //context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/";
                //context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
                //context.HandleResponse();

            };
        });

        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
        var app = builder.Build();
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();

        app.MapBlazorHub();
        app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

***Output :***

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

**Browser output :**

I clicked on **Log in** button as below,

[image]

The Microsoft **"Pick an Account"** pop-up window appeared and I clicked on my account for login as below,

[image]

I logged in now and the default home page is displayed with an option to log out. I clicked on **Log out** button as below,

[image]

The Microsoft **"Pick an Account"** pop-up window appeared and I choosed my account for log out as below,

[image]

I can see the pop-up as **You signed out of your account. It's a good idea to close all browser windows** as below,

[image]

I was successfully logged out as below.

[image]